# jquery fade in then fade out automatically once

Tags: jquery

I want to fade in a text and then fade out it. I just can make it by using click in jquery, but I want it automatically fade in then fade out only once without click. anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean just once at startup?

```
$(function() {

$('p').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).fadeIn('slow');
});

});
```

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/69fxkhdt/

Comment: yes it worked, but I will make it fade in first then fade out.. can I set timer for the fade out? in my case, it will fade in and fade out so fast. I've set $this.fadeOut('10000'); , but it didn't work..

Comment: For this you will need to use `.delay()`.
I have updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/69fxkhdt/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
   $('p').fadeOut('slow');
   $('p').fadeIn('slow');
})
```

Comment: Will those actions take place at the same time, or at different times?